# Understand the Angular way to import JS and CSS files

Tags: angular

I'm just starting with Angular and some concepts are very obscure for me:

1. Why I need to install jquery (`npm install jquery`) and import inside `angular.json` file if I can just download `jquery.js` directly from https://jquery.com/ and add to `assets` folder and after add to `angular.json`?
2. About `angular.json` styles and scripts tags we have the following in Angular documentation:

   > Any CSS files you want to add that you won’t be referencing from your
   >   modules directly, and any JavaScript files that you won’t be importing 
   >   into your TypeScript files

   So, if I need to use some CSS class in a `car.component.html` I shouldn't put this CSS inside `angular.json`? And if I need to use jQuery in a TypeScript class like (`car.service.ts`) i shouldn't put it in `angular.json` too? I see a lot of tutorials that add jQuery in `angular.json` and after import in TypeScript service class.
3. In my understanding Angular's job is only to convert all Angular stuff like modules, directives, typescript and others to a HTML+Javascript single page. Thinking is this way when I look at dist folder I should see only HTML+javascript, without Angular stuff. But looking inside `index.html` in dist folder i saw `<app-root>` and for me this is Angular stuff that should be translated to a HTML piece of code, no?
4. To finish, looking at `index.html` inside dist folder I can't see `jquery.js`, `bootstrap.js` and other JavaScript inserted in `angular.json` file, but everything works fine. This files will be inserted in runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can do it both ways, however, installing packages through NPM is a good practice as it will install any additional dependencies. In addition, it seems way more practical to install/update through NPM with just a command than manually downloading libraries.

2) You should write your CSS in your `car.component.css` stylesheet. No need to add your CSS in your `angular.json`as you do not want it to be applied globally but inside a component.

3) Your understanding is correct! However, bear in mind that you can create any custom tag in HTML. `<app-root>` is actually a custom HTML tag, not an angular thing.

4) These JS libraries are inserted in the main JS file when built. Try to search for them (`ctrl + f`) inside the uglified JS file to get the idea.

Comment: For answer 2), and for JavaScript ? When I shouldn't add the .js inside angular.json?

Comment: You add scripts to the angular.json when you want to include global scripts that are actually not designed to work with angular (for example, you do not have to touch angular.json for modules you 've installed through npm). Another way would be to add them in your index.html, in the head section (traditional way). However, that way they would not be bundled in the build, so adding them via the angular.json is the preferable way.

P.S. Could the downvoter explain why?